# How to concatenate two data in a ViewData at the razor page in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I created a ViewData[] to populate a drop down list. There are 3 fields (Id, Grade and ClzName) in ViewData[]. I need to set ID field to Id and Value field to Grade+ClzName of the drop down list.

I try it as follows but failed. Any one can please help me to resolve it.

controller.cs

```
 private void PopulateSelectClassDDL()
        {
            using (_context)
            {
                List<Class> classList = new List<Class>();
                classList = _context.Classes.ToList();               
                ViewData["classList"] = classList;

            }
        }
```

view.cshtml

```
  @Html.DropDownList("ClzId", new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["classList"],"Id", "Grade" + "ClzName"))
```

Comment: Add a property to the model that returns what you want and use that

Comment: Is it a general property or an internal property?

Comment: is this ok?
[NotMapped]
public string className=> $"{Grade} {ClzName}";

Comment: That should work

Comment: Yes it works. Thz Sami.

Comment: May I know how can I add placeholder to the above drop down list like "Select your Class"?

Comment: Add the parameter to your DropDownList like below:`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountry,  new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["classList"],"Id", "className"), "Select your Class")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to the model that returns what you want and use that
–by Sami Kuhmonen

Then I add following line into my model.

```
[NotMapped] public string className=> $"{Grade} {ClzName}"
```